# Issue with loading Anjuta auto tools plugin

Tags: crash, anjuta

I am using Anjuta (built from source). I am facing an issue where the basic build autotools plugin is not started while starting Anjuta even if I try to enable in preferences (it gets disabled on startup)
If I try to build a project that was already open during start up, anjuta crashes.

Everything works fine, if I open anjuta and then create a new project or if I open Anjuta, close the project (loaded by default) and re-open the same project.

The reason for the crash mentioned earlier : Its unable to load the build configuration (as found by debugging with gdb) - But strangely this happens only when anjuta opens a project while launching anjuta.

Does anyone have any experience with this ?

Comment: I have tried using multiple versions and this is reproduced in all versions (old & new).

Comment: This somewhat sounds as if you do not have `gcc` installed. "It's unable to load the build configuration, as found by gdb" is strange, as gdb does not use the build configuration. Anyway, try deleting the `.anjuta` directory in your project and start anjuta again. Or start Anjuta with `anjuta -n` to ignore the previous settings.